# Uncaught ReferenceError: hr_tb is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tendo problemas com meu JavaScript.

Basicamente, eu pego valores em inputs ao apertar um botão.
Eu usei o mask plugin do jquery pra adicionar mascaras, mas na hora de armazenar os resultados, eu mudo a mascara pra poder fazer contas com o valor, após armazenar, eu mudo a mascara para a anterior somente pelo visual.

No jquery eu pego o valor do input e chamo uma outra função pra fazer um calculo.

(Vou colocar o js incompleto pq é muito grande, mas ele funciona, adicionei essa feature de mask agora e tô tendo esse prolema.

```
function test(){
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#VH").unmask();
    $('#VH').mask('000.00');
    var vl_hr = document.getElementById("VH").value;
    $('#VH').mask('R$:000.00');
    var hr_tb = document.getElementById("HT").value;
    calcular();
});
}


function calcular() {

  var salario_bruto = hr_tb * vl_hr;
```

Se precisarem de mais alguma informação, estarei a disposição.

Erro no console:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: hr_tb is not defined
- at calcular (js.js:31)
- at HTMLDocument. (js.js:24)
- at j (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
- at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
- at m.fn.init.m.fn.ready (jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2)
- at test (js.js:18)
- at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM378 html2.html:67)

Edit: o valor do elemento de id HT está sendo armazenado na var hr_tb (eu verifiquei e o valor consegue ser armazenado, mas o erro persiste).

Answer (score 0):

Mals rapaziada, simplesmente dei uma pesquisada, e vi que uma var se limita ao seu escopo, e não a um arquivo todo. Então a solução que encontrei foi essa:

```
var hr_tb = 0;
var vl_hr = 0;

function calcular() {

  $(document).ready(function (){
      $("#VH").unmask();
      $('#VH').mask('000.00');
      var vl_hr = document.getElementById("VH").value;
      $('#VH').mask('R$:000.00');
      var hr_tb = document.getElementById("HT").value;
    })


  var salario_bruto = hr_tb * vl_hr;
```

Answer (score 0):

A variável `hr_tb` só tem escopo dentro da função do `$(document).ready`. Aliás, não faz sentido colocar o evento `.ready` dentro de uma função, já que esse evento é disparado quando o DOM é carregado. Você está fazendo uso inadequado do evento.

Se você quer que a variável `hr_tb` tenha valor dentro da função `calcular()`, você tem duas opções:

1) Defini-la como variável global: basta tirar o `var`, deixando apenas `hr_tb = document.getElementById("HT").value;`.

2) Enviar como parâmetro para a função `calcular()` (mais recomendado):

```
function test(){
   ...
   var hr_tb = document.getElementById("HT").value;
   calcular(hr_tb);
}

function calcular(hr_tb) {
   ...
}
```